# End of Line Overflow in start of next line

Tags: bash, awk

So I have come across an AWK script that used to be working on HP-UX but has been ported over to RHEL6.4/6.5. It does some work to create headers and trailers in a file and the main script body handles the record formatting.

The problem I am seeing when it runs now is that the last letter from the first line flows onto the start of the next line. Then the last two letters of the second line flow into the start of the third and so on.

This is the section of the script that deals with the record formatting:

```
ls_buffer=ls_buffer $0;
while (length(ls_buffer)>99) {
if (substr(ls_buffer,65,6)=="STUFF") {
.....do some other stuff
} else {
if (substr(ls_buffer,1,1)!="\x01f" && substr(ls_buffer,1,1)!="^") {
    printf "%-100s\n", substr(ls_buffer,1,100);
    }
};
#----remove 1st 100 chars in string ls_buffer
ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,100);
}
```

To start with it looks like the file had picked up some LF,CR,FF so I removed them with gsub hex replacements further up the code but it is ending the line at 100 and then re-printing the last character at the start of the second line.

This is some sample test output just in case it helps:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901    00000012345TESTS SUNDRY PAYME130               DE TESTLLAND GROUP
P1234567890123456789012345678901    00000012345TESTS SUNDRY PAYME131               TESTS RE TESTSLIN
NS1234567890123456789012345678901    00000012345TESTS SUNDRY PAYME132               TESTINGS MORTGAG
GES1234567890123456789012345678901    00000012345TESTS SUNDRY PAYME937               TESTS SUNDRY PA
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that block specifically supposed to be wrapping content like that? It looks like it to me. If the content is greater than 99 characters it hard-wraps it at 100 and then strips 100 characters from the buffer and loops again. Or is the problem that the counts seem off-by-one? Because `substr(ls_buffer,100)` says give me everything from character 100 on (which removes the leading 99 characters).

Comment: I didn't write it but it looks like that is what is meant to be doing. Only on the first loop it prints 100 characters from the buffer. On the next loop it seems to print character 100 again at the start of the second line. The columns should all be perfectly aligned with 100 character width and the 1st column should be all numeric numbers.

Comment: Right. The final substr is off-by-one. It needs to be `substr(ls_buffer, 101)` to chop the first 100 characters off the "buffer". Try this `awk 'BEGIN {f="12345678901234567890"; print substr(f, 1, 10); print substr(f, 10); print substr(f, 11)}'` to see what I mean.

Comment: Did you try to replace `ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,100);` by `ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,99);` ?

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, I will give that a try. The script has been running in a Production environment for about ten years and works wonderfully on HP-UX. I noticed on RHEL if I change printf "%-100s\n", substr(ls_buffer,1,100); to printf "%-100s\n", substr(ls_buffer,0,99);  I get a numeric character that was missing on line one at the start.

Comment: Is each line supposed to be 99 characters or 100? What about lines that are too long? What is supposed to happen to them?

Comment: @EtanReisner, Lines are supposed to be 100 characters long and the source data always provides lines that are 100 characters long apart from in one instance and that character set is converted to a three character set so that it fits the line (in the do some other stuff section).

Comment: That makes me wonder why this is assembling a buffer from source lines that are the correct length only to then chop them up again later but ... something tells me I'm not sure I want to know. Anyway, I think the issue here is likely a difference in `substr` behavior between the versions of `awk`. I'd be curious to see the output from that `awk` snippet in my previous comment on both systems.

Comment: I think maybe someone got an awk manual for Christmas @EtanReisner . The output from your suggested awk on RHEL was (I don't have access to the HP-UX system): 1234567890  01234567890 1234567890

Comment: I would love to see the output from the HP-UX machine (and the version of awk on there) but it isn't a big deal. That output shows you the difference between `substr(X, 10)` and `substr(X, 11)` and seems to explain why you get the output you are. Does the change to `101` fix things?

Comment: Is the entire awk script short (and public) enough to post here?

Comment: @EtanReisner -  Its a pretty big awk script and the rest of it seems to be creating header and footer sections for the output file but defiantly not post able. The rest of it seems to be doing as expected it is only that small section thats giving different output between versions. I will test it in the morning when I find the power cable for my other laptop.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I changed ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,100); to ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,101); and this has fixed the initial formatting issue. I have some questions around the "do some other stuff section" but I can figure that out. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the offsets are incorrect in the manual buffer printing loop.

Specifically that the loop prints 100 characters from the buffer but then strips only 99 characters off the front of the buffer (despite the comments claim to the contrary).

The `substr` function in awk starts at the character position of its second argument. So to drop `x` characters from the front of the string you need to use `x+1` as the argument to `substr`.

Example:

```
# Print the first ten characters from the string.
$ awk 'BEGIN {f="12345678901234567890"; print substr(f, 1, 10)}'
1234567890
# Attempt to chop off the first ten characters from the string.
$  awk 'BEGIN {f="12345678901234567890"; print substr(f, 10)}'
01234567890
# Correctly chop off the first ten characters from the string.
$  awk 'BEGIN {f="12345678901234567890"; print substr(f, 11)}'
1234567890
```

So the `ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,100);` line in the original script would seem to need to be `ls_buffer=substr(ls_buffer,101);` instead.

Given that you claim that the original script is working however I have to wonder if whatever version of `awk` is on that `HP-UX` machine had a slightly different interpretation of `substr` (not that I see how that could be possible).

The above aside this seems like a very odd way to go about this business (manually assembling a buffer and then chopping it up) but without seeing the input and the rest of the script I can't comment much more in that direction.